What part of Homer is Pliny the Elder referring to in Natural History? (On the Use of Paper)
What part of Homer is Pliny the Elder referring to in Naturalis Historia? (On the Use of Paper)

nondum palustria attingimus nec frutices amnium; prius tamen quam digrediamur ab aegypto, et papyri natura dicetur, cum chartae usu maxime humanitas vitae constet, certe memoria. et hanc alexandri magni victoria repertam auctor est M. Varro, condita in aegypto alexandria. antea non fuisse chartarum usum: in palmarum foliis primo scriptitatum, dein quarundam arborum libris. postea publica monumenta plumbeis voluminibus, mox et privata linteis confici coepta aut ceris; pugillarium enim usum fuisse etiam ante troiana tempora invenimus apud homerum, illo vero prodente ne terram quidem ipsam, quae nunc aegyptus, intellegitur, cum in sebennytico et saite eius nomo omnis charta nascatur, postea adaggeratam nilo, si quidem a pharo insula, quae nunc alexandriae ponte iungitur, noctis dieique velifico navigi cursu terram afuisse prodidit. mox aemulatione circa bibliothecas regum ptolemaei et eumenis, supprimente chartas ptolemaeo, idem Varro membranas pergami tradit repertas. postea promiscue repatuit usus rei qua constat inmortalitas hominum.

Plin. Nat. 13.18
(Tuft's Perseus)

In the Loeb this is 13.21. Not sure why it differs from the Teubner.

When he says that pugillares (that is, writing tablets) existed before the Trojan period, he's referring to the story of Bellerophon that Glaucus, a Lycian commander and the cousin of Sarpedon, tells in book 6 of the Iliad—the so-called litterae Bellerophontes passage.
In it, Bellerophon, Glaucus' grandfather, refuses the advances of a woman called Antea, and because of it she lies to her husband, king Proetus, and tells him he tried to rape her. Proetus doesn't have the stomach to kill Bellerophon himself, so he sends him to Lycia with "baleful signs" (σήματα λυγρὰ) scratched into a "folded board" (ἐν πίνακι πτυκτῷ) meant to inspire Antea's father to the task (Il. 6.168-170):

πέμπε δέ μιν Λυκίην δέ, πόρεν δ᾽ ὅ γε σήματα λυγρὰ
γράψας ἐν πίνακι πτυκτῷ θυμοφθόρα πολλά,
δεῖξαι δ᾽ ἠνώγειν ᾧ πενθερῷ ὄφρ᾽ ἀπόλοιτο.
He sent him off to Lycia, giving him
a folded tablet, which he had inscribed
with many dangerous and deadly symbols.
And Proetus told Bellerophon to show it
to Antea's father, so that he would kill him.

(Translation is Emily Wilson's.)
This passage is the only reference to writing or literacy in the Homeric epics, and it presumably predates alphabetic Greek (the fact that it uses σήματα 'signs' rather than γράμματα 'letters', and πίναξ 'board' rather than δέλτος 'writing tablet'—like the alphabet itself a Phoenician loan—is taken as corroborating evidence of that), so since the decipherment of Linear B people have wanted to make the case that it reflects a memory of Linear B, or if not then of Hittite cuneiform (which we know was used for communication between the Mycenaean and the Hittite-Luwian worlds). Both of these writing systems abruptly fell out of use after the Late Bronze Age collapse in the 12th century BCE, and the Trojan War is often taken to have taken place either during or right before the LBA collapse, with the first epic descriptions of it presumably being composed almost immediately, so it would be a very impressive retention if it were.
It's probably not actually a Greek story, however, but one that belongs to the common cultural store of the Ancient Near East and was borrowed, presumably from the Phoenicians during the Orientalising Period. There are parallels in Israelite literature: in Genesis 39 Joseph refuses the advances of Potiphar's wife and is accused of rape by her, and in 2 Samuel 11 David sends Uriah the Hittite to the front with a letter meant to kill him (in that case because he wanted his wife for himself).The writing, then, is neither Linear B nor Hittite cuneiform but just the Phoenician script or Akkadian cuneiform; we've actually found folding wooden writing tablets both in Phoenician shipwrecks and in Nimrud in Assyria, so we know they were used for both.
(It's worth noting that the Greek heroes of the Trojan War themselves are all explicitly illiterate, and that literacy was clearly viewed as a negative, unmanly thing—Proetus' literacy highlights his cowardice in being unable to kill Bellerophon himself. This also tracks with Greek attitudes towards the Phoenicians in general: they saw them as competent but untrustworthy, and while they adopted many of their technologies (like the alphabet) and fashions they never stopped complaining about them.)
But yes, writing tablets are mentioned in Homer, in the Iliad, ante Troiana tempora.

Anatolian hieroglyphs would also seem a potential script for Proteus' board and have the advantage that its use coexisted with Homer (unlike Linear B or Hittite cuneiform)
